# Scanning "false" and "true" as booleans in Redigo

Tags: go, redis, redigo

How can I use `redis.ScanStruct` to parse strings as booleans or even as custom types?

The struct I am using looks like this:

```
type Attrs struct {
    Secret         string `redis:"secret"`
    RequireSecret  string `redis:"requireSecret"`
    UserID         string `redis:"userId"`
}
```

The RequireSecret attribute is either a "true" or "false" string, I'd like to scan it as a `bool`.

Comment: Show the types you are trying to scan and the Redis command that produces the result you are scanning. Implementing the scanner interface may not be the best solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I complement my question with extra info

Comment: What is the Redis command that produces the result you are scanning?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I use HGETALL to view them

Comment: Maybe I'm way off here: I want redis.ScanStruct(values, &attrs) to use a custom parse function for certain attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scan the result of HGETALL, use the following type

```
type Attrs struct {
    Secret         string `redis:"secret"`
    RequireSecret  bool `redis:"requireSecret"`
    UserID         string `redis:"userId"`
}
```

with the following command:

```
values, err := redis.Values(c.Do("HGETALL", key))
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
var attrs Attrs
err = redis.ScanStruct(values, &attrs)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

Because Redigo uses [strconv.ParseBool](https://godoc.org/strconv#ParseBool) to convert Redis result values to `bool`, you don't need to implement the scanner interface to convert `"true"` and `"false"` to `true` and `false`.

You can implement the scanner interface on a subset of a struct's fields. Redigo will use the default parsing for fields that do not implement the interface and the application's custom parser for the fields that do implement the interface.

Unless you need to access individual hash elements through the Redis API, it's usually better store sructs as a Redis string by serializing the struct using JSON, gob or some other encoder.

Comment: Sounds good! But what if I want something fancier, for instance to parse RequireSecret as an enum (I'm planning on supporting more values than "true" and "false" in the future)

Comment: Use a type for the RequireSecret field that implements the scanner interface with the logic you need.

Comment: I see, I didn't know I was supposed to implement the interface on a field. I will try it out :).

Comment: I will make sure to update the question tomorrow when I have more time

Comment: Hey Cerise, I continued the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911105/implementing-redigo-scanner-interface-on-a-structs-field