# Implementing Redigo Scanner interface on a struct's field

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
type authEnum int

const (
    never authEnum = iota
    sometimes
    always
)

type Attrs struct {
    Secret         string   `redis:"secret"`
    RequireSecret  authEnum `redis:"requireSecret"`
    UserID         string   `redis:"userId"`
}

func (e *authEnum) RedisScan(src interface{}) error {
    // This never gets called!
    if e == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("nil pointer")
    }
    switch src := src.(type) {
    case string:
        if src == "false" || src == "never" {
            *e = never
        } else if src == "sometimes" {
            *e = sometimes
        } else { // "always" or "true"
            *e = always
        }
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot convert authEnum from %T to %T", src, e)
    }
    return nil
}

func getAttributes(ctx *AppContext, hash string) (*Attrs, error) {
    rc := ctx.RedisPool.Get()
    values, err := redis.Values(rc.Do("HGETALL", "redishash"))
    rc.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    attrs := Attrs{}
    redis.ScanStruct(values, &attrs)
    return &attrs, nil
}
```

How do I implement the [Scanner](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Scanner) interface on the `RequireSecret` attribute to parse an `authEnum` type out of `"never"`, `"sometimes"` or `"always"` redis hash values?

How do I calculate the value and assign it to the authEnum?
In my code example `RedisScan` never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the method on a pointer receiver. Redis bulk strings are represented as []byte, not string:

```
func (e *authEnum) RedisScan(src interface{}) error {
    b, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot convert authEnum from %T to %T", src, b)
    }
    switch string(b) {
    case "false", "never":
        *e = never
    case "sometimes":
        *e = sometimes
    default:
        *e = always
    }
    return nil
}
```

Always check and handle errors. The error returned from `ScanStruct` reports the type problem.

There's no need to check for nil pointer to the struct member. If the argument to ScanStruct is nil, then Redigo will panic well before the RedisScan method is called.

Comment: Side comment: If you don't need to access struct fields individually through the Redis API, then it's usually better to encode structs to a Redis bulk string using gob, json, yaml.

Comment: Thanks for the clean RedisScan function! However this still never gets called by ScanStruct

Comment: The program at https://play.golang.org/p/6fBVcGOupX works as expected. Confirm that the response from the command contains the field.

Comment: Turns out I was running an old version of redigo, after updating it works!

Answer (score 2):

You don't implement interfaces on fields, but rather on types.

You can make your `authEnum` type satisfy the interface, simply by creating a method with the signature `RedisScan(src interface{}) error` on that type.

To assign to the receiver, you need to receive a pointer.  Then you can assign to it as so:

```
func (e *authEnum) RedisScan(src interface{}) error {
    var value authEnum
    // Logic here to convert src to value
    *e = value
}
```

Comment: For some reason RedisScan is never getting called, is there anything else I need to do to hook it up?

Comment: It is hard to tell without more code. Do you call ScanStruct?

Comment: You may have to change your field type to `*authEnum` (a pointer).

Comment: My code looks like this and using a pointer didn't help https://gist.github.com/herkyl/18f52ade5cc08ed0a7fe2af1c688d2d2

Comment: Turns out my redigo was outdated! After updating it works :)